# isVueInstance is deprecated and will be removed in future releases

Tags: jestjs, deprecated

I am new with JEST and have received the above warning. I want to know which is the alternative since is being deprecated.

Here is the test that I am making:

```
it('is instantiated', () => {
expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
```

});

[image]

Comment: Typically the message that tells you something is deprecated also tells you what to use instead. What is the *exact* message you're seeing?

Comment: @KenWhite nop, It only says that. However, I have checked  https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#isvisible  and found the answer so I posted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how to rigorously check VueInstance

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/blob/2d6b49780c7e1d663b877ddf5d6492ed7b510379/packages/test-utils/src/wrapper.js#L400

```
it('is instantiated', () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I have checked https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#isvisible and they say:

> *Assert Wrapper is Vue instance.*

So the final thing would be:

```
it('is instantiated', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The right answer should be the following:

```js
it('is instantiated', () => {
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

From `test/specs/wrapper/find.spec.js` in vue-test-utils repository,
you can see that when wrapper doesnt exists they assert `Wrapper` object with `exists()`.

```js
  it('returns empty Wrapper with error if no nodes are found', () => {
    const wrapper = mountingMethod(Component)
    const selector = 'pre'
    const error = wrapper.find(selector)
    expect(error.exists()).toEqual(false)
    expect(error.selector).toEqual(selector)
  })
```